# Design Scenario: Smartphone class and will have derived classes like IPhone,AndroidPhone,WindowsMobilePhone can be even phone names with brand

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

This is one of the Java designing question I found on the internet. I tried to solve the question as per my object oriented knowledge.

**You have a Smartphone class and will have derived classes like IPhone,AndroidPhone,WindowsMobilePhone
can be even phone names with brand, how would you design this system of Classes? 
The only detail mentioned as per the requirement wise is that design must be flexible enough to support future products and stable enough to support changes in existing model.**

As per my understanding if I have to provide design for the above question ,then I will create the **Phone** class as abstract class.**Smartphone** class would be the subclass of the Phone class and **IPhone,AndroidPhone,WindowsMobilePhone** are the four subclasses of the **Smartphone** class. 
There would be attribute name **brand** in the **IPhone,AndroidPhone and WindowsMobilePhone classes** to support the phone names with brand. The other possible attributes would be Version Number, Platform, Model number,Model name etc

Please do let me know if above design is correct or not.I need your inputs to improve or correct my solution.

Comment: I don't understand what you want to solve!

Comment: IPhone seems like it wants to be an interface, rather than a class. :-)

Comment: @Harry.Chen: I was just trying to create the possible design of classes based upon the problem statement  marked in bold and my knowledge of design patterns and oop.

Answer (score 4):

Your design seems to be fine.

I would suggest:

1-> Create a  Parent Class "SmartPhone"

2-> It can have SmartPhone must have attributes like Model,Release Year, Brand.

3-> Parent class should also include Smart Phone must have features like Calling,Messaging as abstract methods

3-> For Common SmartPhone features,You can have Interfaces that Indicates SmartPhone common features like Camera,Palyer etc

4-> Then Child Classes like AndroidPhone ,iOSPhone can inherit the SmartPhone Parent Class and shall define all must have attributes and featuresof a SmartPhone.

5-> Child Classes then can implement common features Interfaces , if those features are spported by that Phone.

6->In future if a new SmartPhone Child Class is created, it can also inherit from SmartPhone Parent Class and implement common features via defined interfaces.

7->If in future extra features need be added, new interfaces can be designed for the same and be implemented by the Phones that support it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If we try to expand the design from the current point, I would create subclasses from the IOSPhone,AndroidPhone and WindowsMobilePhone based upon their brand.Say for example Iphone then I would create a one of the subclass as Apple and then create Iphone4,Iphone5 as the subclass of the apple.

Comment: Yes you can do that ! Good Idea! I presented you a rather simple design!!

Comment: And include common features available in all apple Iphones  inside the apple class such  as donotDisturb,batteryStatus etc.  After that we can create Iphone4,Iphone5 as the subclass of the apple. If they are having some unique features then we can have the seperate interfaces such as extendedIphone5 which would have the unique features supported by the IPhone5. Am I going in the correct way ?

Comment: I just created sepearate brandwise classes to such as Apple just to handle the various special features supported by the brands. That I can not maintain  If I would have the single class such as Iphone!